# Single row/single columns query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I have this table:
[datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2VfX.jpg)
I would like to write a single query to update whole 99 by below number so for each 99 will be replaced by number below, for each blank name, the name below.

I tried:

```
update datatable.code set datatable.code= previous (datatable.code)
WHERE datatable.code=99;
```

Comment: What you  have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have some reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: update datatable.code
set datatable.code= previous (datatable.code)
WHERE datatable.code=99; 
But i don't know how to write a previous row (record/item) in sql...

Answer (score 1):

```
update abc set code =
 CASE WHEN name='Jean' THEN 1
      WHEN name='Peter' THEN 2
 END 
 where code=99;
```

Comment: I've just update my problem. Please can you help me more?

Answer (score 0):

use mysql without update

```
select *, 
if(ta.code!=99,ta.code, select ta2.code from table_a as ta2 where ta2.ID_q=ta.ID_q and ta.code!=99 limit 1) as code_a,
if(ta.name!='',ta.name, select ta2.name from table_a as ta2 where ta2.ID_q=ta.ID_q and ta.name!='' limit 1) as name_a 
from table_a as ta;
```